# Capture from multiple streams concurrently, best way to do it and how to reduce CPU usage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ffmpeg

I am currently in the process of writing an application that will capture a lot of RTSP streams(in my case its 12) and display it on the QT widget. The problem arouses when I am going beyond around 6-7 streams, the CPU usage spikes and there is visible stutter.

The reason why I think that it is not QT draw function is because I have done some checking to measure how much time it takes to draw an incoming image from camera and just sample images I had, it is always a lot less than 33 milliseconds(even if there are 12 widgets being updated).

I also just ran opencv capture method without drawing and got pretty much the same CPU consumption as if I was drawing the frames (lost like 10% CPU at most and GPU usage went to zero).

**IMPORTANT: I am using RTSP stream which is a h264 stream.**

**IF IT MATTERS MY SPECS:**

Intel Core i7-6700 @ 3.40GHZ(8 CPUS)
Memory: 16gb
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530

(Also I ran my code on a computer with dedicated Graphics card, it did eliminate some stutter but CPU usage is still pretty high)

I am currently using OPENCV 4.1.0 with GSTREAMER enabled and built, I also have the OPENCV-WORLD version, there is no difference in performance.

I have created a special class called Camera that holds its frame size constraints and various control functions as well stream function. The stream function is being ran on a separate thread, whenever stream() function is done with current frame it sends ready Mat via onNewFrame event I created which converts to QPixmap and updates widget's lastImage variable. This way I can update image in a more thread safe way.

I have tried to manipulate those VideoCapture.set() values, but it didn't really help.

This is my stream function (Ignore the bool return, it doesn't do anything it is a remnant from couple of minutes ago when I was trying to use std::async):

```
bool Camera::stream() {
    /* This function is meant to run on a separate thread and fill up the buffer independantly of
    main stream thread */
    //cv::setNumThreads(100);
    /* Rules for these slightly changed! */
    Mat pre;  // Grab initial undoctored frame
    //pre = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC1);
    Mat frame; // Final modified frame
    frame = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC1);
    if (!pre.isContinuous()) pre = pre.clone();

    ipCam.open(streamUrl, CAP_FFMPEG);


    while (ipCam.isOpened() && capture) {
        // If camera is opened wel need to capture and process the frame
        try {
            auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

            ipCam >> pre;

            if (pre.empty()) {
                /* Check for blank frame, return error if there is a blank frame*/
                cerr << id << ": ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
                for (FrameListener* i : clients) {
                    i->onNotification(1); // Notify clients about this shit
                }
                break;
            }

            else {
                // Only continue if frame not empty

                if (pre.cols != size.width && pre.rows != size.height) {
                    resize(pre, frame, size);
                    pre.release();
                }
                else {
                    frame = pre;
                }

                dPacket* pack = new dPacket{id,&frame};
                for (auto i : clients) {
                    i->onPNewFrame(pack);
                }
                frame.release();
                delete pack;
            }
        }

        catch (int e) {
            cout << endl << "-----Exception during capture process! CODE " << e << endl;
        }
        // End camera manipulations
    }

    cout << "Camera timed out, or connection is closed..." << endl;
    if (tryResetConnection) {
        cout << "Reconnection flag is set, retrying after 3 seconds..." << endl;
        for (FrameListener* i : clients) {
            i->onNotification(-1); // Notify clients about this shit
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));
        stream();
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is my onPNewFrame function. The conversion is still being done on camera's thread because it was called within stream() and therefore is within that scope(and I also checked):

```
void GLWidget::onPNewFrame(dPacket* inPack) {
    lastFlag = 0;

    if (bufferEnabled) {
        buffer.push(QPixmap::fromImage(toQImageFromPMat(inPack->frame)));
    }
    else {
        if (playing) {
            /* Only process if this widget is playing */
            frameProcessing = true;
            lastImage.convertFromImage(toQImageFromPMat(inPack->frame));
            frameProcessing = false;
        }
    }

    if (lastFlag != -1 && !lastImage.isNull()) {
        connecting = false;
    }
    else {
        connecting = true;
    }
}
```

This is my Mat to QImage:

```
QImage GLWidget::toQImageFromPMat(cv::Mat* mat) {



    return QImage(mat->data, mat->cols, mat->rows, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
```

NOTE: not converting does not result in CPU boost (at least not a significant one).

**Minimal verifiable example**

This program is large. I am going to paste GLWidget.cpp and GLWidget.h as well as Camera.h and Camera.cpp. You can put GLWidget into anything just as long as you spawn more than 6 of it. Camera relies on the CamUtils, but it is possible to just paste url in videocapture

I also supplied CamUtils, just in case

Camera.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "FrameListener.h"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include "CamUtils.h"
#include <ctime>
#include "dPacket.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

class Camera
{

    /*
        CLEANED UP!
        Camera now is only responsible for streaming and echoing captured frames.
        Frames are now wrapped into dPacket struct.
    */


private:
    string id;
    vector<FrameListener*> clients;
    VideoCapture ipCam;
    string streamUrl;
    Size size;
    bool tryResetConnection = false;

    //TODO: Remove these as they are not going to be used going on:
    bool isPlaying = true;
    bool capture = true;

    //SECRET FEATURES:
    bool detect = false;


public:
    Camera(string url, int width = 480, int height = 240, bool detect_=false);
    bool stream();
    void setReconnectable(bool newReconStatus);
    void addListener(FrameListener* client);
    vector<bool> getState();    // Returns current state: vector[0] stream state; vector[1] stream state; TODO: Remove this as this is no longer should control behaviour
    void killStream();
    bool getReconnectable();
};
```

Camera.cpp

```
#include "Camera.h"


Camera::Camera(string url, int width, int height, bool detect_) // Default 240p
{
    streamUrl = url; // Prepare url
    size = Size(width, height);
    detect = detect_;

}

void Camera::addListener(FrameListener* client) {
    clients.push_back(client);
}


/*
                TEST CAMERAS(Paste into cameras.dViewer):
                {"id":"96a73796-c129-46fc-9c01-40acd8ed7122","ip":"176.57.73.231","password":"null","username":"null"},
                {"id":"96a73796-c129-46fc-9c01-40acd8ed7122","ip":"176.57.73.231","password":"null","username":"null"},
                {"id":"96a73796-c129-46fc-9c01-40acd8ed7144","ip":"172.20.101.13","password":"admin","username":"root"}
                {"id":"96a73796-c129-46fc-9c01-40acd8ed7144","ip":"172.20.101.13","password":"admin","username":"root"}

*/



bool Camera::stream() {
    /* This function is meant to run on a separate thread and fill up the buffer independantly of
    main stream thread */
    //cv::setNumThreads(100);
    /* Rules for these slightly changed! */
    Mat pre;  // Grab initial undoctored frame
    //pre = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC1);
    Mat frame; // Final modified frame
    frame = Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC1);
    if (!pre.isContinuous()) pre = pre.clone();

    ipCam.open(streamUrl, CAP_FFMPEG);

    while (ipCam.isOpened() && capture) {
        // If camera is opened wel need to capture and process the frame
        try {
            auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

            ipCam >> pre;

            if (pre.empty()) {
                /* Check for blank frame, return error if there is a blank frame*/
                cerr << id << ": ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
                for (FrameListener* i : clients) {
                    i->onNotification(1); // Notify clients about this shit
                }
                break;
            }

            else {
                // Only continue if frame not empty

                if (pre.cols != size.width && pre.rows != size.height) {
                    resize(pre, frame, size);
                    pre.release();
                }
                else {
                    frame = pre;
                }

                auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                std::time_t ts = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
                dPacket* pack = new dPacket{ id,&frame};
                for (auto i : clients) {
                    i->onPNewFrame(pack);
                }
                frame.release();
                delete pack;
            }
        }

        catch (int e) {
            cout << endl << "-----Exception during capture process! CODE " << e << endl;
        }
        // End camera manipulations
    }

    cout << "Camera timed out, or connection is closed..." << endl;
    if (tryResetConnection) {
        cout << "Reconnection flag is set, retrying after 3 seconds..." << endl;
        for (FrameListener* i : clients) {
            i->onNotification(-1); // Notify clients about this shit
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));
        stream();
    }

    return true;
}


void Camera::killStream(){
    tryResetConnection = false;
    capture = false;
    ipCam.release();
}

void Camera::setReconnectable(bool reconFlag) {
    tryResetConnection = reconFlag;
}

bool Camera::getReconnectable() {
    return tryResetConnection;
}

vector<bool> Camera::getState() {
    vector<bool> states;
    states.push_back(isPlaying);
    states.push_back(ipCam.isOpened());
    return states;
}
```

GLWidget.h:

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include "FrameListener.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "FrameListener.h"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include "Camera.h"
#include "CamUtils.h"
#include <qstyleoption.h>
#include "dPacket.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <qmenu.h>
#include "FullScreenVideo.h"
#include <QMovie>
#include "helper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>

class Helper;

class GLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, public FrameListener
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget(std::string camId, CamUtils *cUtils, int width, int height, bool denyFullScreen_ = false, bool detectFlag_=false, QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    void killStream();
    ~GLWidget();

public slots:
    void animate();
    void setBufferEnabled(bool setState);
    void setCameraRetryConnection(bool setState);
    void GLUpdate();            // Call to update the widget
    void onRightClickMenu(const QPoint& point);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;
    void onPNewFrame(dPacket* frame);
    void onNotification(int alert_code);


private:
    // Objects and resourses
    Helper* helper;
    Camera* cam;
    CamUtils* camUtils;
    QTimer* timer; // Keep track of update
    QPixmap lastImage;
    QMovie* connMov;
    QMovie* test;

    QPixmap logo;

    // Control fields
    int width;
    int height;
    int camUtilsAddr;
    int elapsed;
    std::thread* camThread;
    std::string camId;
    bool denyFullScreen = false;
    bool playing = true;
    bool streaming = true;
    bool debug = false;
    bool connecting = true;
    int lastFlag = 0;


    // Debug fields
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point lastFrameAt;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point now;
    std::chrono::duration<double> painTime; // time took to draw last frame

    //Buffer stuff
    std::queue<QPixmap> buffer;
    bool bufferEnabled = false;
    bool initialBuffer = false;
    bool buffering = true;
    bool frameProcessing = false;



    //Functions
    QImage toQImageFromPMat(cv::Mat* inFrame);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
    void drawImageGLLatest(QPainter* painter, QPaintEvent* event, int elapsed);
    void drawOnPaused(QPainter* painter, QPaintEvent* event, int elapsed);
    void drawOnStatus(int statusFlag, QPainter* painter, QPaintEvent* event, int elapsed);
};

#endif
```

GLWidget.cpp:

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include <future>


FullScreenVideo* fullScreen;

GLWidget::GLWidget(std::string camId_, CamUtils* cUtils, int width_, int height_,  bool denyFullScreen_, bool detectFlag_, QWidget* parent)
    : QOpenGLWidget(parent), helper(helper)
{
    cout << "Player for CAMERA " << camId_ << endl;

    /* Underlying properties */
    camUtils = cUtils;
    cout << "GLWidget Incoming CamUtils addr " << camUtils << endl;
    cout << "GLWidget Set CamUtils addr " << camUtils << endl;
    camId = camId_;
    elapsed = 0;
    width = width_ + 5;
    height = height_ + 5;
    helper = new Helper();
    setFixedSize(width, height);
    denyFullScreen = denyFullScreen_;

    /* Camera capture thread */
    cam = new Camera(camUtils->getCameraStreamURL(camId), width_, height_, detectFlag_);
    cam->addListener(this);

    /* Sync states */
    vector<bool> initState = cam->getState();
    playing = initState[0];
    streaming = initState[1];
    cout << "Initial states: " << playing << " " << streaming << endl;
    camThread = new std::thread(&Camera::stream, cam);
    cout << "================================================" << endl;

    // Right click set up
    setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);


    /* Loading gif */
    connMov = new QMovie("establishingConnection.gif");
    connMov->start();
    QString url = R"(RLC-logo.png)";
    logo = QPixmap(url);
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(GLUpdate()));
    timer->start(1000/30);
    playing = true;

}

/* SYSTEM */
void GLWidget::animate()
{
    elapsed = (elapsed + qobject_cast<QTimer*>(sender())->interval()) % 1000;
    std::cout << elapsed << "\n";
}


void GLWidget::GLUpdate() {
    /* Process descisions before update call */
    if (bufferEnabled) {
        /* Process buffer before update */
        now = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> timeSinceLastUpdate = now - lastFrameAt;
        if (timeSinceLastUpdate.count() > 25) {
            if (buffer.size() > 1 && playing) {
                lastImage.swap(buffer.front());
                buffer.pop();
                lastFrameAt = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            }
        }
        //update(); // Update
    }
    else {
        /* No buffer */
    }
    repaint();
}


/* EVENTS */
void GLWidget::onRightClickMenu(const QPoint& point) {
    cout << "Right click request got" << endl;

    QPoint globPos = this->mapToGlobal(point);
    QMenu myMenu;

    if (!denyFullScreen) {
        myMenu.addAction("Open Full Screen");
    }
    myMenu.addAction("Toggle Debug Info");


    QAction* selected = myMenu.exec(globPos);

    if (selected) {
        string optiontxt = selected->text().toStdString();

        if (optiontxt == "Open Full Screen") {
            cout << "Chose to open full screen of " << camId << endl;
            fullScreen = new FullScreenVideo(bufferEnabled, this);
            fullScreen->setUpView(camUtils, camId);
            fullScreen->show();
            playing = false;
        }

        if (optiontxt == "Toggle Debug Info") {
            cout << "Chose to toggle debug of " << camId << endl;
            debug = !debug;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Chose nothing!" << endl;
    }


}



void GLWidget::onPNewFrame(dPacket* inPack) {
    lastFlag = 0;

    if (bufferEnabled) {
        buffer.push(QPixmap::fromImage(toQImageFromPMat(inPack->frame)));
    }
    else {
        if (playing) {
            /* Only process if this widget is playing */
            frameProcessing = true;
            lastImage.convertFromImage(toQImageFromPMat(inPack->frame));
            frameProcessing = false;
        }
    }

    if (lastFlag != -1 && !lastImage.isNull()) {
        connecting = false;
    }
    else {
        connecting = true;
    }
}


void GLWidget::onNotification(int alert) {
    lastFlag = alert;   
}


/* Paint events*/


void GLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

        if (lastFlag != 0 || connecting) {
            drawOnStatus(lastFlag, &painter, event, elapsed);
        }
        else {

            /* Actual frame drawing */
            if (playing) {
                if (!frameProcessing) {
                    drawImageGLLatest(&painter, event, elapsed);
                }
            }
            else {
                drawOnPaused(&painter, event, elapsed);
            }
        }
    painter.end();

}


/* DRAWING STUFF */

void GLWidget::drawOnStatus(int statusFlag, QPainter* bgPaint, QPaintEvent* event, int elapsed) {

    QString str;
    QFont font("times", 15);
    bgPaint->eraseRect(QRect(0, 0, width, height));
    if (!lastImage.isNull()) {
        bgPaint->drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, width, height), lastImage);
    }
    /* Test background painting */
    if (connecting) {
        string k = "Connecting to " + camUtils->getIp(camId);
        str.append(k.c_str());
    }
    else {
        switch (statusFlag) {
        case 1:
            str = "Blank frame received...";
            break;

        case -1:
            if (cam->getReconnectable()) {
                str = "Connection lost, will try to reconnect.";
                bgPaint->setOpacity(0.3);
            }
            else {
                str = "Connection lost...";
                bgPaint->setOpacity(0.3);
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    bgPaint->drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, width, height), QPixmap::fromImage(connMov->currentImage()));
    bgPaint->setPen(Qt::red);
    bgPaint->setFont(font);
    QFontMetrics fm(font);
    const QRect kek(0, 0, fm.width(str), fm.height());
    QRect bound;
    bgPaint->setOpacity(1);
    bgPaint->drawText(bgPaint->viewport().width()/2 - kek.width()/2, bgPaint->viewport().height()/2 - kek.height(), str);

    bgPaint->drawPixmap(bgPaint->viewport().width() / 2 - logo.width()/2, height - logo.width() - 15, logo);

}



void GLWidget::drawOnPaused(QPainter* painter, QPaintEvent* event, int elapsed) {
    painter->eraseRect(0, 0, width, height);
    QFont font = painter->font();
    font.setPointSize(18);
    painter->setPen(Qt::red);
    QFontMetrics fm(font);
    QString str("Paused");
    painter->drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, width, height),lastImage);
    painter->drawText(QPoint(painter->viewport().width() - fm.width(str), 50), str);

    if (debug) {
        QFont font = painter->font();
        font.setPointSize(25);
        painter->setPen(Qt::red);
        string camMess = "CAMID: " + camId;
        QString mess(camMess.c_str());
        string camIp = "IP: " + camUtils->getIp(camId);
        QString ipMess(camIp.c_str());
        QString bufferSize("Buffer size: " + QString::number(buffer.size()));
        QString lastFrameText("Last frame draw time: " + QString::number(painTime.count()) + "s");
        painter->drawText(QPoint(10, 50), mess);
        painter->drawText(QPoint(10, 60), ipMess);
        QString bufferState;
        if (bufferEnabled) {
            bufferState = QString("Experimental BUFFER is enabled!");
            QString currentBufferSize("Current buffer load: " + QString::number(buffer.size()));
            painter->drawText(QPoint(10, 80), currentBufferSize);
        }
        else {
            bufferState = QString("Experimental BUFFER is disabled!");
        }
        painter->drawText(QPoint(10, 70), bufferState);
        painter->drawText(QPoint(10, height - 25), lastFrameText);
    }
}


void GLWidget::drawImageGLLatest(QPainter* painter, QPaintEvent* event, int elapsed) {
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    painter->drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, width, height), lastImage);
    if (debug) {
        QFont font = painter->font();
        font.setPointSize(25);
        painter->setPen(Qt::red);
        string camMess = "CAMID: " + camId;
        QString mess(camMess.c_str());
        string camIp = "IP: " + camUtils->getIp(camId);
        QString ipMess(camIp.c_str());
        QString bufferSize("Buffer size: " + QString::number(buffer.size()));
        QString lastFrameText("Last frame draw time: " + QString::number(painTime.count()) + "s");
        painter->drawText(QPoint(10, 50), mess);
        painter->drawText(QPoint(10, 60), ipMess);
        QString bufferState;
        if(bufferEnabled){
            bufferState = QString("Experimental BUFFER is enabled!");
            QString currentBufferSize("Current buffer load: " + QString::number(buffer.size()));
            painter->drawText(QPoint(10,80), currentBufferSize);
        }
        else {
            bufferState = QString("Experimental BUFFER is disabled!");
            QString currentBufferSize("Current buffer load: " + QString::number(buffer.size()));
            painter->drawText(QPoint(10, 80), currentBufferSize);
        }
        painter->drawText(QPoint(10, 70), bufferState);
        painter->drawText(QPoint(10, height - 25), lastFrameText);

    }
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    painTime = end - start;
}



/* END DRAWING STUFF */



/* UI EVENTS */

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e) {

    if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        if (fullScreen == nullptr || !fullScreen->isVisible()) { // Do not unpause if window is opened
            playing = !playing;
        }
    }

    if (e->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
        onRightClickMenu(e->pos());
    }
}



/* Utilities */
QImage GLWidget::toQImageFromPMat(cv::Mat* mat) {



    return QImage(mat->data, mat->cols, mat->rows, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();



}

/* State control */

void GLWidget::killStream() {
    cam->killStream();
    camThread->join();
}

void GLWidget::setBufferEnabled(bool newBufferState) {
    cout << "Player: " << camId << ", buffer state updated: " << newBufferState << endl;
    bufferEnabled = newBufferState;
    buffer.empty();
}

void GLWidget::setCameraRetryConnection(bool newState) {
    cam->setReconnectable(newState);
}

/* Destruction */
GLWidget::~GLWidget() {
    cam->killStream();
    camThread->join();
}
```

CamUtils.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;

class CamUtils
{
private:

    string camDb = "cameras.dViewer";
    map<string, vector<string>> cameraList; // Legacy
    json cameras;
    ofstream dbFile;
    bool dbExists(); // Always hard coded

    /* Old IMPLEMENTATION */
    void writeLineToDb_(const string& content, bool append = false);
    void loadCameras_();

    /* JSON based */
    void loadCameras();

public:
    CamUtils();
    string generateRandomString(size_t length);
    string getCameraStreamURL(string cameraId) const;
    string saveCamera(string ip, string username, string pass); // Return generated id
    vector<string> listAllCameraIds();
    string getIp(string cameraId);
};
```

CamUtils.cpp:

```
#include "CamUtils.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib")  // UuidCreate - Minimum supported OS Win 2000
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

CamUtils::CamUtils()
{
    if (!dbExists()) {
        ofstream dbFile;
        dbFile.open(camDb);
        cameras["cameras"] = json::array();
        dbFile << cameras << std::endl;
        dbFile.close();

    }
    else {
        loadCameras();
    }
}




vector<string> CamUtils::listAllCameraIds() {
    vector<string> ids;
    cout << "IN LIST " << endl;
    for (auto& cam : cameras["cameras"]) {
        ids.push_back(cam["id"].get<string>());
        //cout << cam["id"].get<string>() << std::endl;
    }
    return ids;
}

string CamUtils::getIp(string id) {
    vector<string> camDetails = cameraList[id];
    string ip = "NO IP WILL DISPLAYED UNTIL I FIGURE OUT A BUG";
    for (auto& cam : cameras["cameras"]) {
        if (id == cam["id"]) {
            ip = cam["ip"].get<string>();
        }
    }

    return ip;
}

string CamUtils::getCameraStreamURL(string id) const {
    string url = "err"; // err is the default, it will be overwritten in case id is found, dont forget to check for it

    for (auto& cam : cameras["cameras"]) {
        if (id == cam["id"]) {
            if (cam["username"].get<string>() == "null") {
                url = "rtsp://" + cam["ip"].get<string>() + ":554/axis-media/media.amp?tcp";
            }
            else {
                url = "rtsp://" + cam["username"].get<string>() + ":" + cam["password"].get<string>() + "@" + cam["ip"].get<string>() + ":554/axis-media/media.amp?streamprofile=720_30";
            }
        }
    }

    return url;  // Dont forget to check for err when using this shit
}


string CamUtils::saveCamera(string ip, string username, string password) {
    UUID uid;
    UuidCreate(&uid);
    char* str;
    UuidToStringA(&uid, (RPC_CSTR*)&str);
    string id = str;
    cout << "GEN: " << id << endl;
    json cam = json({}); //Create emtpy object
    cam["id"] = id;
    cam["ip"] = ip;
    cam["username"] = username;
    cam["password"] = password;
    cameras["cameras"].push_back(cam);
    std::ofstream out(camDb);
    out << cameras << std::endl;
    cout << cameras["cameras"] << endl;

    cout << "Saved camera as " << id << endl;
    return id;
}


bool CamUtils::dbExists() {
    ifstream dbFile(camDb);
    return (bool)dbFile;
}





void CamUtils::loadCameras() {
    cout << "Load call" << endl;
    ifstream dbFile(camDb);
    string line;
    string wholeFile;

    while (std::getline(dbFile, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
        wholeFile += line;
    }
    try {
        cameras = json::parse(wholeFile);
        //cout << cameras["cameras"] << endl;

    }
    catch (exception e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    dbFile.close();
}










/*
    LEGACY CODE, TO BE REMOVED!

*/



void CamUtils::loadCameras_() {
    /* 
        LEGACY CODE:
        This used to be the way to load cameras, but I moved on to JSON based configuration so this is no longer needed and will be removed soon
    */

    ifstream dbFile(camDb);
    string line;
    while (std::getline(dbFile, line)) {
        /*
            This function load camera data to the map:
            The order MUST be the following: 0:ID, 1:IP, 2:USERNAME, 3:PASSWORD.
            Always delimited with | no spaces between!
        */
        if (!line.empty()) {
            stringstream ss(line);
            string item;
            vector<string> splitString;

            while (std::getline(ss, item, '|')) {
                splitString.push_back(item);
            }
            if (splitString.size() > 0) {
                /* Dont even parse if the program didnt split right*/
                //cout << "Split string: " << splitString.size() << "\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < (splitString.size()); i++) cameraList[splitString[0]].push_back(splitString[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}



void CamUtils::writeLineToDb_(const string & content, bool append) {
    ofstream dbFile;
    cout << "Creating?";
    if (append) {
        dbFile.open(camDb, ios_base::app);
    }
    else {
        dbFile.open(camDb);
    }

    dbFile << content.c_str() << "\r\n";
    dbFile.flush();
}

/* JSON Reworx */




string CamUtils::generateRandomString(size_t length)
{
    const char* charmap = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const size_t charmapLength = strlen(charmap);
    auto generator = [&]() { return charmap[rand() % charmapLength]; };
    string result;
    result.reserve(length);
    generate_n(back_inserter(result), length, generator);
    return result;
}
```

**End of example**

How would I go about decreasing CPU usage when dealing with large amount of streams?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Edited, removed extra questions.

Comment: Can you supply a [mcve]?

Comment: Done, I copied the "problem" classes, you can run them as is with few obvious changes.

Comment: Thanks! This increases your chances of the question getting answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I have done some reading and found out about TAPI (OpenCV's transparent-API).

Essentially it is bunch of function overloads that take UMat instead of Mat. The thing about those overloaded functions is that the calculations on those UMats will be done on the dedicated graphics hardware IF AVAILABLE(it uses OpenCL so it is fairly standard and straight forward). I have redone my capture method to utilize UMat(I do convert to normal Mat before sending it to my widget specifically due to the fact that I did not want to bother with rewriting a conversion function in GLWidget. It is still pretty fast). With these fixes I get about 36-37% CPU utilization and around 60% on GPU(which is built in) which is exactly

```
bool Camera::stream() {
    /* This function is meant to run on a separate thread and fill up the buffer independantly of
    main stream thread */

    ipCam.open(streamUrl, CAP_FFMPEG);

    while (ipCam.isOpened() && capture) {

        UMat frame;  // Grab initial undoctored frame
        // If camera is opened wel need to capture and process the frame 

        try {
            ipCam >> frame;

            if (!frame.empty()) {
                UMat temp;
                cvtColor(frame, temp, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
                frame = temp;
                if (frame.cols != size.width && frame.rows != size.height) {
                    resize(frame, temp, size);
                    frame = temp;
                }

                dPacket* pack = new dPacket;
                pack->camId = id;
                Mat t;
                t = frame.getMat(ACCESS_FAST);
                pack->frame = &t;
                if (t.empty()) cout << "WTF" << endl;
                for (auto i : clients) {
                    i->onPNewFrame(pack);
                }

                // Clean up:
                t.release();
                frame.release();
                temp.release();
                delete pack;

            }
            else {
                /* Blank frame caught */
                cerr << id << ": ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
                for (FrameListener* i : clients) {
                    i->onNotification(1); // Notify clients about this shit
                }
                break;

            }


        }

        catch (int e) {
            cout << endl << "-----Exception during capture process! CODE " << e << endl;
        }
        // End camera manipulations
    }

    cout << "Camera timed out, or connection is closed..." << endl;
    if (tryResetConnection) {
        cout << "Reconnection flag is set, retrying after 3 seconds..." << endl;
        for (FrameListener* i : clients) {
            i->onNotification(-1); // Notify clients about this shit
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));
        stream();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Quite a simple fix, but is very impactful. I will be also doing some more reading about this.

**It is important to note that this work around is best to use when you have A LOT of processing to do and utilizing GPU will help in your code, HOWEVER this is not a panacea, you should still probably use Mat for small things.**