# I wan to use qt to view more than one camera feed and it's really slow

Tags: c++, qt6

I want any suggestion for making qt faster when dealing with multiple cameras at once it's making my PC very slow

Comment: FYI: [SO: Capture from multiple streams concurrently, best way to do it and how to reduce CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56656065/7478597), [SO: Multiple video play on QT application simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35308404/7478597), [SO: Embed separate video streams in Qt widgets on embedded-linux using Gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67054782/7478597), and more with [google "qt multiple camera streams site:stackoverflow.com"](https://www.google.com/search?q=qt+multiple+camera+streams+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: Please, note also the effort which the OPs invested into their questions. Your question (sorry to say) doesn't show much effort. Less chances to get a sufficient answer IMHO... (And the tag spamming won't change that to the positive angle.)

Comment: ok i will change that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.